# How to find closest string match in a large set a variables in python?

Tags: python, list, variables, search, chatbot

I need to find a way to find the most similar string to what the user has inputted within lists within individual variables variables.

```
L666485 = [u9027, m616, "CHELMSFORD, ", "Yes?"]
L666461 = [u9027, m616, "CHELMSFORD, ", "Thank you."]
L666460 = [u9029, m616, "CREALOCK, ", "The only reports of enemy activity have come from the direction of the Royal Kraal, at Ulundi."]
L666385 = [u9027, m616, "CHELMSFORD, ", "Our runners bare his dispatches, do they not?"]
```

eg. The variable is name starts with a L followed by a number, there is then a list which contain (in left to right order) the character ID, movie ID, character name, line said.
I need to search the line said of every L variable list item [3]

I am creating a chat bot using python which uses the cornell movie-dialogs corpus to search through and find a line similar to a line said within the scripts, 
the code should then find the conversation this matches and then find the next line said. 
I have looked into `difflib.get_close_matches` but as far as I can tell this only searches a list within a singular variable.

```py
#List of variables
from movie_variables import *

def main():
    #user input 
    user_input = input(":// ")

    #This is something that I would like it to do
    #use difflib.get_close_matches to search movie variables for something similar to user_input
    matching_line = difflib.get_close_matches(user_input, movie_variables[3])
```

Ideally I would like it to output the variable ID for the line that is similar eg. L6551

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: As @VaughanHilts pointed, you can use Levenshtein distance as a metric. It is available as a [python package](https://github.com/ztane/python-Levenshtein).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the variable name at the starting of the list and just return it like `movie_variables[0]`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow. Start of what list?

Comment: I meant that you can store the variables as `L666485 = ["L666485",u9027, m616, "CHELMSFORD, ", "Yes?"] ` and return the variable ID for the line that is similar.